# Hover acting weird in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a look at this HTML code:

```
<div class="overlay">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
</div>
```

and this jQuery code:

```
$('div.overlay').mouseenter(function() { clearTimeout(thumbsAway); });
$('div.overlay').mouseleave(function() { clearTimeout(thumbsAway); $('ul.thumbs').animate({top: '520px'}, 750); });
```

The problem is that in IE, hovering on any child element will also trigger mouseenter/mouseleave. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$('div.overlay').hover(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    clearTimeout(thumbsAway);
  },
  function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    clearTimeout(thumbsAway);
  }
);
```

Or check the target of the event.

```
$('div.overlay').hover(function(event){
    if (this == event.target){clearTimeout(thumbsAway);}
  },
  function(event){
    if (this == event.target){clearTimeout(thumbsAway);}
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the event propogation with [`stopPropogation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$('div.overlay').mouseenter(function(e) {
  e.stopPropogation();
  clearTimeout(thumbsAway);
});
```

---

> Description: Prevents the event from
>   bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing
>   any parent handlers from being
>   notified of the event.